# how to assign dw value of ax register to db variable?

Tags: assembly, x86

I add values of array into `AL` and then I do `AAM` command to get the decimal of the sum. Register `ax` shows `AH=03 AL=04` which is 34.

I need to assign the value 34 into variable sum.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: No, you have `AX=0304h`, not decimal 34.  Do you actually want to calculate `10*AH + AL`?  If so, you should have left out the `AAM` in the first place so you still have one single byte integer in AL which will fit in a `db`.  Or do you want to store the 2-byte unpacked-BCD value somewhere?  Or `add ax, '00'` to turn it into ASCII digits first (in the opposite of printing order, because x86 is little-endian but you want the high digit at the low address).

Answer (score 2):

```
...           ; AL=34
aam           ; -> AH=3 AL=4
```

Starting with the value 34 in `AL`, the `aam` instruction will give you `AH=3` and `AL=4`.

To restore the value that you started with you can use the `aad` instruction. This one will multiply `AH` by 10, then add `AL`.

> AAD
>
> AL <- AH * 10 + AL
>   AH <- 0

Hereafter you can move `AL` to your byte-sized *sum* variable.

```
...           ; AL=34
aam           ; -> AH=3 AL=4
aad           ; -> AX=34
mov [sum], al
...
sum db 0
```

Shorter (because there's not much sense in doing `aam` and `aad` in a row):

```
...           ; AL=34
mov [sum], al
...
sum db 0
```

---

> how to assign dw value of ax register to db variable?

If your destination variable is byte-sized, you can never assign a word-sized quantity to it!
The desire to assign `AX` to a `db` variable only makes sense if `AX` holds a value that is less than 256 in which case you just assign `AL` (the low half of `AX`) to the `db` variable.